# Fixing Parallax Issues with CSS

Tags: css, parallax

I am attempting to edit the pure css parallax code shown here: codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw

What I'm trying to do is edit the code so the parallax sections are half the height they are currently. When I change the code to say `50vh`, the background images are cut off or repeat and do not display properly.

I tried changing the height of the slide class to `50vh` and the #slide1:before class to background-attachment: fixed; which made the first slide appear fine but the third slide still looked the same.

Answer (score 0):

vh and vw are used for their abilities to keep things re-sized correctly in the viewport. With vw/vh, we can size elements to be relative to the size of the viewport. A viewport is the view in the window. Viewports are generally used to make a webpage feel more like an app by preventing the screen from moving around of mobile devices.

**Solution: The problem is that you are selecting all four options for padding to be 25vh when it should receive all four explicitly defined values.**

```
.slide {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12vh 25vh 12vh 25vh;
  min-height: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  transform-style: inherit;
}
```

**(also for margins)another way to write it out to be more readable is:**

```
  padding-left: 25vh;
  padding-right: 25vh;
  padding-top: 12vh;
  padding-bottom: 12vh;
```

**update Solution:** 
My next guess would be that this could be a browser compatibility issue with using vh and vw as I'm not extremely familiar with using them and when I try my browser(Chrome 42) it works fine. There are millions to skin millions of cats when it comes to web dev. Did you try using a different form of measurement? [Here is link with a complete list of them.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this code and the padding was reduced but the background image is still cut off or repeating in the background. I think it has something to do with the background-attachment:fixed or something like that.

Comment: My next guess would be that this could be a browser compatibility issue with using vh and vw as I'm not extremely familiar with using them and when I try my browser(Chrome 42) it works fine. There are millions to skin millions of cats when it comes to web dev. Did you try using a different form of measurement? Here is link with a complete list of them.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length